# Vue Js form submit does not respond after form have been submitted twice

Tags: forms, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am new to VueJS and I tried to make a form using Vue and Vuetify.

I don't know what happens but after the form have been submitted twice with `@submit.stop.prevent`, any button on the page won't work anymore. Here is my code:

```html
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-app-bar>
      <v-app-bar-nav-icon></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
      <v-app-bar-title>My Vue App</v-app-bar-title>
      </v-app-bar>
      <v-row class="pa-6">
        <v-col
          cols="12"
          sm="6"
          offset-sm="3"
        >
          <v-card
          >
            <v-list lines="two">
              <v-list-subheader>Today</v-list-subheader>
                <li style="list-style: none;" v-for="store in stores" :key="store.id">
                  <v-list-item
                  prepend-avatar="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/lists/1.jpg"
                  >
                 
                    <template v-slot:subtitle>
                      <v-list-item-title>{{store.cTitle}}</v-list-item-title> 
                      <span class="font-weight-bold">{{store.cName}}</span> &mdash; {{store.cComment}}
                    </template>
                  </v-list-item>
                </li>            
                <v-divider inset></v-divider>
            </v-list>
            
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      <form @submit.stop.prevent="addComment" class="text-center">
        <v-col class="">
          <v-row class="mb-3 text-center" align="center" justify="center">
            <h3>Name</h3>
          </v-row>
          <v-row class="mb-3 text-center" align="center" justify="center">
            <input v-model="name" class="mb-3 border border-primary" type="text" name="name" id="name" :style="{width:'20%', height:'2em'}"/>
          </v-row>
          <v-row class="mb-3 text-center" align="center" justify="center">
            <h3>Title</h3>
          </v-row>
          <v-row class="mb-3 text-center" align="center" justify="center">
            <input v-model="title" class="mb-3 border border-primary" type="text" name="title" id="title" :style="{width:'20%', height:'2em'}"/>
          </v-row>
          <v-row class="mb-3 text-center" align="center" justify="center">
            <h3>Comment</h3>
          </v-row>
          <v-row class="mb-3 text-center" align="center" justify="center">
            <input v-model="comment" class="mb-3 border border-primary" type="text" name="comment" id="comment" :style="{width:'20%', height:'2em'}"/>
          </v-row>
        </v-col>
         <div class="text-center">
          <button
            class="mb-5"  
            depressed
            align="center"
            justify="space-round">
              Add Comment
         </button>
        </div>
        
      </form>
      
      <div class="text-center">
        <v-pagination
          v-model="page"
          :length="4"
          :total-visible="4"
        ></v-pagination>
      </div>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'App',

  data() {
    return{
      page:1,
      id:0,
      name:'',
      title:'',
      comment:'',
      stores:[] 
    }
  },
  methods:{
    addComment(){
      this.stores.push({ id: this.id++, cName: this.name, cTitle: this.title, cComment: this.comment })
      this.name = ""
      this.title = ""
      this.comment = ""
    }
  }

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works perfectly fine based on your example (I can totally add more objects to `stores`).

```html
<v-list-item prepend-avatar="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/lists/1.jpg">
  <v-list-item-title>{{store.cTitle}}</v-list-item-title>
  <span class="font-weight-bold">{{store.cName}}</span> &mdash; {{store.cComment}}
</v-list-item>
```

There is no such thing as `<template v-slot:subtitle>` tho, as [shown here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-list-item/#slots).
So removing it solves the issues and prints the content.

Further debugging could be achieved thanks to the Vue devtools.

Comment: i checked and the data actually is successfully pushed into the array but the loop stop after the second loop. i got this error message when i checked on console:
runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:2779 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')

Comment: @DennisNg I cannot replicate this issue with the code you  shared, works perfectly fine on my side.

Comment: can i ask what usually cause this kind of error? thanks

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
    at invokeDirectiveHook (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:2779:1)
    at Array.eval (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:5349:1)
    at flushPostFlushCbs (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:339:1)
    at flushJobs (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:393:1)

Comment: This happens when something on the left side of `.value` is undefined. This can happen because of a lot of things, hard to say here. Do you have other errors? Your code works on my side.

Comment: I checked and the data actually went into the array it's just that it stopped the loop after the second data was shown. I checked and the error message is just the one i sent before. Thanks anyway for the help!!!

Comment: What do you see in your Vue devtools? I don't see why it would stop after 2 elements in the array.

Comment: ```
<!-- <v-list-item prepend-avatar="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/lists/1.jpg"> -->
                      <v-list-item-title>{{storages[i].cTitle}}</v-list-item-title>
                      <span class="font-weight-bold">{{storages[i].cName}}</span> &mdash; {{storages[i].cComment}}
                  <!-- </v-list-item>   -->```

it seem that the v-list-item that i commented cause the problem, after i commented those lines of code it seem to be able to work fine.